# Iterate over MongoDB collection and remove documents per two consecutive ids

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

Is there any fast and efficient way to iterate over MongoDB collection and remove documents per two consecutive ids?

My collection documents have the following format:

```
{ 
"_id" : "USD/JPY-2011-04-13T09:34:04.365Z", 
"pair" : "USD/JPY", 
"dateTime" : ISODate("2011-04-13T09:34:04.365+0000"), 
"bid" : 83.98, 
"ask" : 83.992, 
"bidVolume" : 1.309999942779541, 
"askVolume" : 1.5
```

}

For the time being, the only work-around I have found to remove documents based on datetime is:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { "dateTime":{ $lte : ISODate("2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") } } ).remove();
bulk.execute();
```

but it's really slow, removing approx. 10,000 documents per second (my collection consists of 5 Billion documents).

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking. Not only does the code you list NOT "remove per two consecutive" but it's also not necessary in that form as ALL MongoDB CRUD API methods use the "Bulk" interface underneath anyway. So `db.collection.deleteMany({ "datetime": { "$lte" : new Date("2012-01-01") } })` is exactly the same thing. But still nothing to do with the text or title of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Neil. Maybe you're right, what I posted was just a conventional way to remove documents from a MongoDB collection but what I implied (..or originally wanted to say) was a suggestion/tip for how to transform this statement into "remove per two consecutive" documents. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a quick & easy way to do this:

```
var cnt = 0;
var docsToDelete = [];

db.collection_name
  .find( { "dateTime":{ $lte : ISODate(threshold_timestamp) } } )
  .forEach( function(myDoc) 
            {
                if (cnt % 2 == 0){  
                    docsToDelete.push(myDoc._id);
                }
                cnt++;
            }
  );
db.dc_historic_ticks.remove({'_id':{'$in': docsToDelete}});
```